# How to convert all items (options) of a multi select dropdown into an array using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to convert a multiple select dropDown values (all options) into an array using jquery.

```
<select size="10" style="width: 330px;" name="itemList"
        id="selectedItemLists" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">value1</option>
    <option value="2">value2</option>
    <option value="3">value3</option>
    <option value="4">value4</option>
</select>
```

Now using jquery how to create an array like array[0]=value1,array[1]=value2...

Please help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All options, or all *selected* options?

Answer (score 7):

Possibly something like:

```
var options = new Array();
$('#selectedItemLists > option:selected').each(
     function(i){
         options[i] = $(this).val();
     });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4wvpw/).

---

**Edited** in response to @mellamokb's comment, to amend the jQuery to use `text()` instead of `val()`:

```
var options = new Array();
$('#selectedItemLists > option:selected').each(
     function(i){
         options[i] = $(this).text();
     });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4wvpw/1/).

References:

- [`:selected` selector](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: +1 Technically, for OP's requirements, I think you'd want `.text();` http://jsfiddle.net/ZeGKP/

Comment: I believe the preferred way to intialize an array in JavaScript is `[]`, not `new Array()`: http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) to accomplish this as well.

```
var i = $.map($("#selectedItemLists option:selected"), function(elem){
    return $(elem).text();
});
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/EwNDv/)**

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery `map` method is useful here.

```
$('select option').map(function(index, elem){
    return $(elem).text();
});
```

(Mark beat me to it, but mine uses the `map` method of the collection rather than the "static" jQuery.map function.  Both are fine, of course.)